# Split function when writing an opened file in Python

Tags: python, list, split, position

So I have a program in which I am supposed to take an external file, open it in python and then separate each word and each punctuation including commas, apostrophes and full stops. Then I am supposed to save this file as the integer positions of when each word and punctuation occurs in the text.

For eg:- I like to code, because to code is fun. A computer's skeleton.

In my program, I have to save this as:-

1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

(Help for those who do not understand)
1-I , 2-like, 3-to, 4-code, 5-(,), 6-because, 7-is, 8-fun 9-(.), 10-A, 11-computer, 12-('), 13-s, 14-skeleton

So this has displayed the positions of each of word, even if it repeats, it shows the first occuring postion of the same word

Sorry for the long explanation but here is my actual question. I have done this so far:-

```
    file = open('newfiles.txt', 'r')
    with open('newfiles.txt','r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                 print(word)
```

And here is the result:-

```
  They
  say
  it's
  a
  dog's
  life,.....
```

Unfortunately this way to split a file does not separate words from punctuation and it does not print out horizontally. .split does not work on a file, does anyone know a more effective way in which i can split the file - words from punctuation? And then store the separated words and punctuation together in a list?

Comment: `line.spilt` has to split from where? means which line in your code you assume `line.split` has to `split` but not `spliting` ? `print` add `\n` after each function, you can override this, and print line `horizontally`.

Comment: `.split` works on *strings*, not files, which is what you are doing here (you iterate over the file, line by line, each line being a string). Without any arguments, `split` splits on *whitespace*.

Comment: @Lafada I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So do you know how i can split not using white space, because i have to split up punctuation not just the words too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in string method `.split` can only work with simple delimiters. Without an argument, it simply splits on *whitespace*. For more complex splitting behavior, the easiest thing is to use regex:

```
>>> s = "I like to code, because to code is fun. A computer's skeleton."
>>> import re
>>> delim = re.compile(r"""\s|([,.;':"])""")
>>> tokens = filter(None, delim.split(s))
>>> idx = {}
>>> result = []
>>> i = 1
>>> for token in tokens:
...     if token in idx:
...         result.append(idx[token])
...     else:
...         result.append(i)
...         idx[token] = i
...         i += 1
...
>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 9]
```

Also, I don't think you need to iterate over the file line by line, as per your specifications. You should just do something like:

```
with open('my file.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Which will put the entire file as a string into `s`. Note, I never used `open` before the `with` statement, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @StreetSoldier there was a bug, it is now fixed. It requires a bit more logic in the for-loop.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to say thx in the comments but i have been stuck on this for so long. Thx for helping me out, i am so grateful :-)

Comment: Is there a function in which we can reverse what we just did? What i mean is, take the compressed file (the positions of the word) and then using those positions recreate the entire text with punctuation? I've searched for it a lot but i don't seem to find anything

Comment: @StreetSoldier You'd have to maintain the dictionary somewhere. The `idx` `dict` can be inverted with no information loss (since there is a one-to-one mapping). Something like `idx_to_toke = {v:k for k,v in idx.items()}`. Then use `idx_to_toke[i]` for each `i` in the compressed file. Then `" ".join` that sequence you get. You will lose any white-space information, though. All whitespace becomes a single space: `" "`

Comment: Sorry for occupying so much of your time, but can you simplify/explain what you mean - for me to write the code - from the 4th sentence onwards?

Comment: Have you made a list of the separated individual words? As in, the words that make up the text,even if the text has repeating words, the list only has different words - it never has the same one in it. Can you tell me how to make such a list as i tried so, using your program but i cant seem to figure it out. PS - it's for the second part of this program which I AM going to make MYSELF. :-)

Comment: @StreetSoldier You have the `idx` dictionary. It's a mapping from words/tokens (so it includes punctuation) to first-seen index.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to capture the relevant substrings:

```
import re

my_string = "I like to code, because to code is fun. A computer's skeleton."
matched = re.findall("(\w+)([',.]?)", my_string) # Split up relevant pieces of text
```

Filter out the empty matches and add to the result:

```
result = []
for word, punc in matched:
    result.append(word)
    if punc: # Check if punctuation follows the word
        result.append(punc)
```

Then write the result to your file:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(result) # Write pieces on separate lines
```

---

The regex works by finding alpha characters, then checking if there is punctuation following (optionally).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with using regex and split.  Hope this points you in the right direction.  Good luck!

```
import re
str1 = '''I like to code, because to code is fun. A computer's skeleton.'''

#Split your string into a list using regex and a capturing group:
matches = [x.strip() for x in re.split("([a-zA-Z]+)", str1) if x not in ['',' ']]
print matches
d = {}
i = 1
list_with_positions = []

#now build the dictionary entries:
for match in matches:
    if match not in d.keys():
        d[match] = i
        i+=1
    list_with_positions.append(d[match])

print list_with_positions
```

Here is the output.  Notice that there is a final period with a position of #9:

['I', 'like', 'to', 'code', ',', 'because', 'to', 'code', 'is', 'fun', '.', 'A', 'computer', "'", 's', 'skeleton', '.']

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 9]