# Indexes of a list Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find how to print the indexes of words in a list in Python. If the sentence is "Hello world world hello name") I want it to print the list "1, 2, 2, 1, 3")

I removed all duplicates of words with this:

```
sentence = input("Enter").lower()
words = sentence.split()
counts = []
for word in words:
    if word not in counts:
       counts.append(word)
print(counts)
```

But I need to still get indexes of the sentence using an array

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split function when writing an opened file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726645/split-function-when-writing-an-opened-file-in-python)

Comment: So you want the list to be a list of indexes of the first occurance of the word? Please see [ask]

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I think the OP means the third unique word in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index to be the "nth unique word I see in the sentence" then this code would produce this:

```
sentence = "Hello world world hello name".lower()
first_occurence = dict()
for pos, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if word not in first_occurence:
        first_occurence[word] = len(first_occurence)

res = [first_occurence[word] + 1 for word in sentence.split(' ')]
```

result: `[1, 2, 2, 1, 3]`