# How do i make the numbers added to the numbers list apply to the indexes of the list of words without any numbers being skipped

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a program that takes a list of words(text) and adds numbers to the numbers lists(called numbers) to represent the indexes of the original text e.g. the phrase "the sailor went to sea sea sea to see what he could see see see but all that he could see see see was the bottom of the deep blue sea sea sea" should be returned as "1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 6 7 8 9 6 6 6 10 11 12 8 9 6 6 6 13 1 14 15 16 17 5 5 5" however is returned as "1 2 3 4 5 5 5 4 9 10 11 12 9 9 9 13 14 15 11 12 9 9 9 16 1 17 18 1 19 20 5 5 5", causing a problem.

This is the part of the program that is the problem:

```
for position, item in enumerate(text):
    if text.count(item) < 2:
        numbers.append(max(numbers) + 1)
    else:
        numbers.append(text.index(item) + 1)
```

The "numbers" and "text" are both lists.

Comment: Did your [entire class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726645/split-function-when-writing-an-opened-file-in-python/41727022#41727022) decide to use StackOverflow to work on assignment? Y'all would probably benefit form doing this yourselves or talking amongst each other.

Comment: What?                           ...........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to get the create a version of the text without duplicates, but maintaining the same order, and finding indexes of the words in the original text from that list using `index()`:

Create a list from the string by splitting by spaces:

```
text="the sailor went to sea sea sea to see what he could see see see but all that he could see see see was the bottom of the deep blue sea sea sea"
listText=text.split(" ")
```

Create new list without duplicates containing all words in text, using `count()` to check word has not appeared previously:

```
unique_text=[listText[x] for x in range(len(listText))if listText[:x].count(listText[x])<1]
```

Use list comprehension to get index of every word in `listText` in unique_text(and add 1):

```
positions=[unique_text.index(x)+1 for x in listText]
```

Final code:

```
text="the sailor went to sea sea sea to see what he could see see see but all that he could see see see was the bottom of the deep blue sea sea sea"
listText=text.split(" ")
unique_text=[listText[x] for x in range(len(listText))if listText[:x].count(listText[x])<1]
positions=[unique_text.index(x)+1 for x in listText]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 6, 6, 10, 11, 12, 8, 9, 6, 6, 6, 13, 1, 14, 15, 1, 16, 17, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I wasted hours trying to do this and your response fixed my program for good. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with dictionaries :

```
text="the sailor went to sea sea sea to see what he could see see see but all that he could see see see was the bottom of the deep blue sea sea sea" 
l=text.split(' ')
d=dict()
cnt=0
for word in l :
    if word not in d : 
       cnt+=1
       d[word]=cnt 
out=[d[w] for w in l]  

#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 6, 6, 10, 11, 12, 8, 9, 6, 6, 6, 13, 1, 14, 15, 1, 16, 17, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: How can I split up the "d" variable into separate lists with the positions and the words?

Comment: you can obtain them by pos=d.values() and words=d.keys(). you can convert them in list by list(pos).

Comment: Is there also a way that I can keep these in the same places where they were before as I tried .sort and it put the words in the right order but not the positions

Comment: Is there a way to modify my own code to fix the error?